# Why does it matter from where you call DispatchQueue.main.async?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

I wrote the following pieces of code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.cameraManager.checkForCameraAuthorization(deniedCallback: {
        self.presentDeniedAlert()
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }) {
        self.cameraAccess = true
        self.cameraButton.isEnabled = false
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

and

```
cameraManager.checkForMicrophoneAuthorization(deniedCallback: {
    self.presentDeniedAlert()
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.microphoneAccess = true
            self.microphoneButton.isEnabled = false
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

(the difference is from where async is called)

The 1. crashes `self.cameraButton.isEnabled = false can only be called from main thread`

The 2. one finishes just fine.

Can someone explain, why this is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diff is as explained below.

In the **1st** code your `checkForCameraAuthorization` callback is executing in a different thread, and you should know UIApplication/UI related task should execute in the main thread.

In the **2nd** code after getting the callback in `checkForCameraAuthorization` you are executing the UI related task in the main thread, so its works fine.

If any doubt plz comment.

Comment: So that the function is called from .main.async doesn't mean that the callback is called in this thread? E.g. the callback is still not called from .main.async, right?

Comment: Yes right, you submitted entire task into main queue, but that doesn't mean callback will also happen in the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch queues are thread-safe which means that you can access them from multiple threads simultaneously. Always update UI elements from the main queue.

In first code you are updating UI on different threads not from Main Thread.

For more Refrences you can follow these link -

https://www.quora.com/Why-must-the-UI-always-be-updated-on-Main-Thread#

https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2